# How to extract data of a spatial index into my PHP app?

Tags: php, zend-framework, geolocation, spatial, point

I have a spatial index of type POINT in my table that stores the geo-coordinates of some location.

I have been able to successfully insert a POINT into my table using this:

```
$point = new Zend_Db_Expr("GeomFromText('POINT(-12.461334 130.841904)')");
$property->setLocation($point);
```

I am using Zend, and I'm trying to figure out how I can extract the latitude and longitude values back out into my application. Can anyone offer me any help with this?

Right now I am using the following code to return my the stored value of the POINT.

```
$properties->getLocation();
```

Isn't there some PHP function which would get me back -12.461334 130.841904

Comment: The latlng is in a binary data format, you should extract with an SQL statement X(latlng) or Y(latlng).

Answer (score 0):

I learned that if you are saving the values as Geometry points is because you are going to try to use the available [Geometry Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/geometry-property-functions.html) such as 'GLength' or 'LineString', to calculate distances or boundaries, then you are going to output a value most generally a float, take this table as an example

```
event
id -> int -> 11 -> unsigned -> primary -> auto increment
name -> varchar -> 255
location -> point
```

Using this query, you would get the distance between the provided lat, long position and the values of the rows inside the table event

```
SELECT
    ev.id,
    ev.name,
    (
        GLength(
            LineString(
                (
                    PointFromWKB(
                        POINT(
                            32.660629,
                            -117.106354
                        )
                    )
                ),
                (
                    ev.location
                )
            )
        )
    ) * 100
    AS distance
FROM
event ev
```

and as a result you get

```
=====================================
= id = name     = distance          =
=====================================
= 1  = event x  = 16.956332397071797=
=====================================
```

To implement this as a Zend query you would do something similar to this, ( depending on your implementation and where do you get your $table value )

```
$point = new stdClass();
$point->lat = 32.660629;
$point->lon = -117.106354;
$table = $this->getDbTable();
$resultSet = $table->fetchAll(
    $table->select()
        ->from(
            $table,
                array(
                    'id',
                    'name',
                    new Zend_Db_Expr("
                            (
                                GLength(
                                    LineString(
                                        (
                                            PointFromWKB(
                                                POINT(
                                                    {$from->lat},
                                                    {$from->lon}
                                                )
                                            )
                                        ),
                                        (
                                            location
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            ) * 100
                            AS 'distance'
                    "
                    ),
                    'category',
                    'user'
                )
            )
        );
```

Hope this helps.